# What do we call the table which links any other two tables?

Tags: database, database-design

Suppose I have two master tables called **User** and **Role**. There is a third table named **RoleofUser** which tells the role of each user. What do we call the **RoleofUser** table, is there any specific name to tables like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have usually seen the name "bridge" or "junction" table being used to describe what the `RoleofUser` table is in your schema.  This name is given because `RoleofUser` serves as a logical *bridge* between the `User` and `Role` tables.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) seems to prefer going with junction table.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it **JoinTable**. It will contain primary key from both the tables as foreign key which will together form composite primary key.